# How to get submitted number into the input form outside modal angular

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to make modal that have button and input manual number, so when get submit the number would be on the input outside the modal. and then can be use for many stuff like activate time minutes with the number and more. I try so many ways but I only can get the number from console.log for now and prevent from redirect to ? when i press the button. When I try input manual the number is null.

How to make a good modal that can get a number to the input outside the modal?

```html
<div class="flex flex-col  w-full justify-center my-2" *ngIf="status === 'Preparing'">
            <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog('0ms', '0ms')">Input Target Time ( Button )</button>
            <form class="p-1" [formGroup]="timerForm">

                <div class="mb-2">Target Time (minutes)</div>
                <button
                  (click)="clickButton(60)"
                  class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2"
                >
                  60
                </button>
                <button
                  (click)="clickButton(120)"
                  class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2"
                >
                  120
                </button>
                <button
                  (click)="clickButton(180)"
                  class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2"
                >
                  180
                </button>
                <button
                  (click)="clickButton(240)"
                  class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2"
                >
                  240
                </button>
              <div>
                <input
                  class="border-2 mt-3 w-full px-3 py-1 rounded-md text-black"
                  formControlName="timer"
                  [value]="timerForm.value.timer"
                  type="number"
                  placeholder="time charging on minutes"
                />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

```html
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Choose Target Time</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <button
                  (click)="clickButton(60)"
                  class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2"
                >
                  60
                </button>
                <button
                  (click)="clickButton(120)"
                  class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2"
                >
                  120
                </button>
                <button
                  (click)="clickButton(180)"
                  class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2"
                >
                  180
                </button>
                <button
                  (click)="clickButton(240)"
                  class="bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 cursor-pointer w-10 h-10 rounded-md mx-2"
                >
                  240
                </button>

              <form class="p-1" formGroup="timerForm">
                <div class="mb-2">Target Time (minutes)</div>

                <div>
                  <input
                    class="border-2 mt-3 w-full px-3 py-1 rounded-md"
                    formControlName="timer"
                    [value]="timerForm.value.timer"
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="time charging on minutes"
                  />
                </div>
              </form>

  <button type="submit" (click)="handleClose()" mat-dialog-close [disabled]="false" mat-button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

```html
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-animations-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-animations-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogAnimationsExampleDialog implements OnInit{
  public active = false;
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogAnimationsExampleDialog>) {}

  public timerForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    timer: new FormControl()
  });

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  @Output() cancel: EventEmitter<undefined> = new EventEmitter();

  public onCancel(e: PointerEvent): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.closeForm();
  }

  public closeForm(): void {
    this.active = false;
  }

  public clickButton(num: number) {
    this.timerForm.value.timer = num
    this.closeForm();
  }


  public handleClose(){
    console.log(this.timerForm.value.timer)
    this.dialogRef.close()
  }

}
```

Comment: I think what you need is what the `EventEmitter` is for

Comment: how to use it EventEmitter on this case?

Comment: In the dialog on close you emit an event which you listen to on the parent element, or am I not understanding your problem?

Comment: yes when close the dialog, i want that result will be in my input

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the result from the modalRef you create when you open the modal, subscribing to afterCLosed():

```
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogAnimationsExampleDialog, {
      data: {inputValue: this.inputValue},
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed, result: ', result);
    });
```